# cs7003 unexpected use of an unbound generic name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm getting this error in Visual Studio:

> Error CS7003  Unexpected use of an unbound generic name   MyProject
>   C:\Users[myname]\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects....\Index.cshtml   1

The offending file is right here (line 1 error is the reference to the model declaration):

```
@model MyProject.Models.MyAccount.Details
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_PrimaryLayout.cshtml";
}
<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">
.... more page stuff follows from here
```

The model class is as follows:

```
namespace MyProject.Models.MyAccount
{
    public class Details
    {
        public static Details Select(Company c)
        {
            Details model = new Details();
            model.SomeProperty = "SomeValue";


            return model;
        }

        public String SomeProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The weird thing is that cleans don't make it go away, rebuilds leave it there, and I build/debug just fine.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It took shutting down Visual Studio and restarting for the error to clear. Subsequent rebuilds do not produce the error.

Comment: I didn't have to restart visual studio 2017, just clean and rebuild the solution.

Comment: I'm sad that 5 years later this is still the solution.

Comment: also 7 years later with latest VS 2022 17.7.0 Preview 1.0

Answer (score 13):

Just cut the line `@model` and save, then paste it again and save, it should be gone.

Answer (score 12):

I made a mistake that took me quite a while to see.
I created a generic method:

```
public static T MyMethod<T>() { ... }
```

By mistake, I wrote in my code

```
var something = MyMethod<>();
```

It compiled but at runtime it threw the error "unexpected use of an unbound generic name".

If ever you made the same mistake, you might try to search "<>" in your code...

Comment: Thank you sir, just ran into this and it was bizarre because VS didn't give me a red squiggly line...

Answer (score 4):

I had the same message.
I moved the @model at first line and the error gone.

Comment: I thought I saw the same, but after moving the @model line back to where it was didn't make the error return. Must have just triggered a refresh or something.

Answer (score 3):

For me it was at a Blazor app, inside the view of a component. I used type parameter like this (some code was omitted)

```
@typeparam T

@if (Current.Expanded)
{
    <ul>
        @foreach (var child in Current.Children)
        {
            <li>
                <TreeNodeView Current="child" T="@T" />
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

and got such an error message ("Unexpected use of an unbound generic name") with the red underlining after "child" at "Current="child"". And my component was rendered incorrectly. But after I had deleted the "@" symbol at "T="@T"", the error disappeared and the componet was rendered correctly.

Comment: Just had the same thing. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this when editing a Net 7 Blazor Server app running VS 2022 (17.5.0). I cleaned*, shutdown VS and then delete the hidden .vs folder (at the root of the solution directory structure). Problem went away.

*Mads Clean Solution VS extension removes obj/bin folders on VS shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this editing a Blazor Server dotnet 6 app. I use Telerik and in my `TelerikGrid` component I had specified a value for `TItem`. I removed it (I guess I didn't need it because it could infer the type of the collection from the `Data` property) and the error went away.

Perhaps something changed at some point wih an update to the Telerik components.